# how to get data in dio.post in this form {"xxx","xxx"}

Tags: flutter, http-post, dio

I want to post data using dio in this format

```
{"abc","abc"}
```

these values should be come from text box
how i can do that?

i am doing it like this

```
var data=<String, String>{
          'email': user.email,
          'password': user.password
        };

// var data={
//   "username":name,
//   "password":password
// };
  try{
  return await dio.post("https://attendance-demo.herokuapp.com/login",
      data:data,
}
```

it is sending in this way[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way

```
response = await dio.post("https://attendance-demo.herokuapp.com/login", data: {'email': 123, 'password': '123'});
```

Comment: when i pass data: {'email': name, 'password': password}  , i m not getting values on it

Comment: basically these name and password are the parameter of function and that function i m calling on button